# Subdirectories not generated after upgrade

Tags: hugo

I have a documentation site generated using hugo. It was working fine until I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04. I guess that also upgraded hugo.

Now index.html is generated, with links to sub directories but the html for content subdirectories are not generated.

No configuration or code or layout has changed. Just hugo version update. Current version is 0.40.1.

I am using Material Docs theme. Can there be compatibility issues of a theme with hugo version?

How do I go about debugging the same?

Have posted the question at discourse.gohugo.io as well.

Comment: Reverting back to 0.15 version of hugo fixed the issue.

Note that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has 0.15 version of hugo.

After trying multiple older versions, I found out that this breakage happened in 0.32 version.
My guess is that it is related to Page Bundles feature. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since .32 version of hugo there is a change. Renaming top level index.md to _index.md solved the issue.